# Unable to subscribe to a kespace event using StackExchangeRedisCacheClient.Subscribe<T>

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using StackExchange.Redis library to connect to a windows-based redis server. The server is configured with 
    notify-keyspace-events "AKE"

The code is very basic, because I'm new to Redis, and thus am experimenting in a simple windows forms application.
This is what I do trying to trigger the events:

```
var serializer = new NewtonsoftSerializer();
var cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(SafeConn, serializer, "");
cacheClient.Add<FOO>(key, fooInstance);
```

SafeConn is a property that gets a ConnectionMultiplexer in a thread-safe way.

If I subscribe using this code

```
ISubscriber subscriber = SafeConn.GetSubscriber();
subscriber.Subscribe(new RedisChannel("__keyspace@0__:ID:*", RedisChannel.PatternMode.Pattern),
    (channel, value) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("!!!!");
    });
```

I manage to catch the event.
Hovewer, if I try to do it using this code:

```
var serializer = new NewtonsoftSerializer();
var cacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(SafeConn, serializer, "");
cacheClient.Subscribe<FOO>(new RedisChannel("__keyspace@0__:*", 
RedisChannel.PatternMode.Pattern), x =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(x.Title);
});
```

The event won't trigger. I might be bad at googling, but I'm unable to find anything on the topic. I'll be very grateful for any help.

Comment: I tried supplying different patterns, even providing an exact key and PatternMode.Literal. Doesn't seem to affect the outcome.

Comment: When subscribed using ISubscriber, the channel value contains the key, thus I can probably extract it and use it to get the value and do stuff. Just feels like inventing a bicycle when it's potentially implemented in an extension.

Comment: This is more related to the [StackExchange.Redis.Extensions](https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions) extension. Maybe open a bug there. Or try different library like the one I've worked on [CachingFramework.Redis](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis#keyspace-notifications-api) that also provides keyspace notifications.

Comment: I was able to implement what I needed with the basic subscription (Which is what if I understand correctly pretty much the same the library you suggested does) and it works like a charm. Thanks anyway.